# Passing $_GET variable with smarty htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, smarty

I'm having difficulty trying to pass over the $_GET variable (event) which is the url. The website is built with PHP and Smarty template engine and mod_rewrite works fine.

Working link/Querystring:

**/index.php?page=event&url=special-event-name**

Rewrite:

**/events/special-event-name**

htacces:

**RewriteRule   ^events/(.+)/?$     index.php?page=event&url=$1 [L]**

When viewing the page **/events/special-event-name** it is looking for the template **special-event-name.inc.html**.

I need it to use the template **event.inc.html** and show the $_GET variable url **special-event-name**.

I also have another rule for **/events/** which shows template **events.inc.html**.

**RewriteRule   ^events/?$    index.php?page=events  [NC]**

Comment: What is the question? Does /events/special-event-name/ work? (Note the additional / at the end)

Comment: No /events/special-event-name doesn't work, smarty is looking for special-event-name.inc.html instead of using the template event.inc.html and displaying the event (url field) "special-event-name"

Comment: This url works:
/index.php?page=event&url=special-event-name

but the mod-write doesn't work

Comment: Your second rewrite rule is too greedy.

Comment: I've removed the second rule for now, yet smarty is still looking for special-event-name.inc.html

Comment: Actually I'm not sure anymore, what the real problem is. Is it the rewrite of the request or the mechanism of the request itself?

Comment: The rewritten URL should work, but on the page the database content does not load, instead it shows a Smarty error as it's looking for special-event-name.inc.html... That inc template doesn't exist, the template it should be using is event.inc.html and 'special-event-name' is the unique 'URL' field (instead of a number ID) in the database telling it which event to show.